# React asynchronous state update causing unresponsive User Experience

Tags: reactjs, react-native, performance, react-hooks, react-context

My top-level React component provides a context to all its children which is used to render UI. The context is an array, and a UI element is generated for each element in the array. Users can delete items from this array using buttons placed around the app and throughout the component tree.

The problem is when an element is deleted, the context takes a really long time to update and the app feels unresponsive. I know it's because it's async, but it's causing UX issues.

How can I make my app more responsive? Is there a way to force a state update?

I'm not sure how to approach fixing this. Would a state management lib work?

Comment: "I know it's because it's async"

is there even a loading indicator?

Comment: "Is there a way to force a state update?" - from my understandig, if you modify the `context's` elements, you realize that already with a state update, don't you? So I don't think you could speed up things with another state update (or any kind of triger for rerender).

Comment: Could you please provide some codes that you have done related to this? So that it would be easy for anyone to understand and give you a proper solution

Comment: Please show the code you are using to update your context. Probably the long delay is due to the way you are updating your array - you may be filtering on an ID, for example, which requires the function to go through every element in the array. A faster solution is to store your array as an object with IDs as keys; then you can update an ID with something like `deleted: true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue with Chrome being a memory hog. I cleared caches and cookies, restarted chrome + server, and everything started working. What a silly thing to spend hours profiling your react app for! Hopefully this can help someone else.